CircuitBreaker not showing up in springboot application
I am working on a spring boot application broken in multiple microservices. I am currently trying to set up a circuit breaker and I do not manage to see it on the actuator.
I tried to set up this function in my AccountController
  @PostMapping("/create/{userID}")
    @CircuitBreaker(name = "accountService")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createAccount(@RequestBody AccountDTO account, @PathVariable Long userID) {
        log.info("Creating account for user ID: {}", userID);
            CashUserDTO user = cashUserServiceProxy.findById(userID);
            if (user == null) {
                log.error("User not found for ID: {}", userID);
                return new ResponseEntity<>("No user found.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            } else {
                AccountDTO createdAccount = accountsService.createAccount(account, userID);
                EntityModel<AccountDTO> model = toModel(createdAccount, userID);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(model, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
    }

and my application.properties looks like this
spring.application.name=accountService

spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8070/
server.port=8083

management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health



spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cashmate
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.sql.init.mode=never
spring.sql.init.platform=mysql


resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.register-health-indicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.accountService.minimum-number-of-calls=5
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.accountService.failure-rate-threshold=70
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.accountService.wait-duration-in-open-state=10000
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.accountService.permitted-number-of-calls-in-half-open-state=1

management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0

And the /actuator/health looks like this
{"status":"UP","components":{"clientConfigServer":{"status":"UP","details":{"propertySources":["configClient"]}},"db":{"status":"UP","details":{"database":"MySQL","validationQuery":"isValid()"}},"discoveryComposite":{"status":"UP","components":{"discoveryClient":{"status":"UP","details":{"services":[]}},"eureka":{"description":"Eureka discovery client has not yet successfully connected to a Eureka server","status":"UP","details":{"applications":{}}}}},"diskSpace":{"status":"UP","details":{"total":290824646656,"free":289731194880,"threshold":10485760,"path":"D:\\coding\\CashMateCloud\\config-server\\.","exists":true}},"ping":{"status":"UP"},"reactiveDiscoveryClients":{"status":"UP","components":{"Simple Reactive Discovery Client":{"status":"UP","details":{"services":[]}},"Spring Cloud Eureka Reactive Discovery Client":{"status":"UP","details":{"services":[]}}}},"refreshScope":{"status":"UP"}}}

please send help.
